# Operand clash with date table and varchar date strings in cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, cross-join, ssms-2017

This follows on from my previous question, but since I tried to simplify, I appear to have missed something [Daily snapshot table using cte loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211232/daily-snapshot-table-using-cte-loop)

I am trying to set up the below cross join between dates and an employee table. I need a daily count according to division and department, but the dates won't link easily since the dates are stored as varchar (not my choice, I can't change it).

I now have a date table that includes a style112 (yyyymmdd) key that I can link to the table, but there seems to be a failure somewhere along the joins.

I'm so close, but really am lost! I have never had to work with string dates and wouldn't wish it upon anyone.

```
    DECLARE @DATESTART AS Date = '20180928';

    DECLARE @DATEEND AS Date = '20181031';

    WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT  @DATESTART AS Dte
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DTE + 1
        FROM Dates
        WHERE Dte <= @DATEEND  )

    SELECT
        Dt.Dte
        ,CAST(DTC.Style112 AS VARCHAR)
        ,Emp.Division_Description
        ,Emp.Department_Description
        ,(SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM ASS_D_EmpMaster_Live E

            WHERE
                E.[Start_Date] <= CAST(DTC.Style112 AS VARCHAR)
                AND (E.Leaving_Date > CAST(DTC.Style112 AS VARCHAR)
                            OR E.Leaving_Date = '00000000')
                                 ) Counts
    FROM Dates Dt

    LEFT JOIN ASS_C_DateConversions DTC
        ON DTC.[Date] = Dt.DtE


        CROSS JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    Division_Description
                    ,Department_Description
                FROM
                    ASS_D_EmpMaster_Live e              
                ) Emp

    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Desired output:

Date
           Dept1
   Dept2   
Dept3

20180901
      25 
      231
      154

20180902
      23 
      232
      154

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Sorry I went back to tag it as SSMS. And I'm working on results example, thanks.

Comment: Can you try to simplify the problem? If I have to scroll, I just leave.

Comment: Unfortunately simplifying is how I got here. I've taken out the unnecessary WHEREs, but I worry about any more.

Comment: If you're saying that `DTC.Style112` contains string-like values in the format yyyymmdd, then why the `cast(… as varchar)`?

Comment: @Richardissimo This was added after I initially got the operand clash; it is already in that format.

Comment: I would have thought you want to cast it as `date`. What are the types of `E.[Start_Date]` and `E.Leaving_Date`?

Comment: Richardissimo is right. You need to cast the start and leaving dates to char values and not the `Style112` values. Use `char(8)` rather than `varchar`.

Comment: Start and Leaving dates are varchar, which is the crux of my problem. I am trying to get around this with Style112 conversions, but I can't get a cross join to work without a date table in date format and my start/leave dates in varchar. It's the bane of my life, but the database won't change sadly.

Comment: Are they not in the right format? You need to cast to `date` and then back to `char` in the format you need. I also presume that your subquery needs to filter on the department and division in order to return the different counts. Maybe that's something that got stripped during the simplification.

Comment: @shawnt00 No they're varchar yyyymmdd strings. Which should I cast and recast; the start/leave date or the actual date from the date table? <br> I have tried to convert the date-table-date to match the start-date, which is where I assume the clash is likely occurring, but my fix attempts aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the conversion table at all and I would remove it. And I believe the subquery should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ASS_D_EmpMaster_Live E
WHERE
         CAST(E.Start_Date   AS DATE) <= Dt.Dte
    AND (CAST(E.Leaving_Date AS DATE) >  Dt.Dte OR E.Leaving_Date = '00000000')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" when I run the above and "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" if I remove quotes around the "dates".

Comment: Maybe use `try_parse()` on the leaving date conversion?

Comment: NULL result, unfortunately!

Comment: @eelyface What do these dates look like?

Comment: They're varchar '20180401'. I can cast to int, but that's about it, it seems.

Comment: That's castable to date. You need to post specific error messages or something.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the above, it's helped me figure out the bulk of the problem: One date is castable, but another is not. I don't know why this is, but the entire query works so long as I don't use Leaving Date, which I will consider a different issue altogether. Thanks for continuing to reply, I appreciate it.

Comment: It's because some of the leaving date values are all zeroes, which is not a valid date. You might try `cast(nullif(leavingDate, '00000000') as date)`

Comment: Thanks for this. This combined with excluding anything before 01/01/2017 (some sort of faulty data) has solve the issue. Thank you for your help; I would not have got there otherwise.